# Расположение блоков в div

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы блоки лежали один на другом? Есть

```
<div >
   <div class = "0"/>
   <div class = "1"/>
</div>
```

И нужно чтоб 1 лежал на 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
}

.box1 {
  background: blue;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}

.box2 {
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

[Демо](https://jsfiddle.net/xfs084gf/4/)